# Recursive query to join Hierarchy Level table to count how many times the second level hierarchies appear in the divisision + Zipcode table

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

So, I have three SQL tables, Hierachy Level and ZipCode.

Example of tables: (Please bear in mind that this is just an example and that in reality there is N numbers of hierarchy levels in the system, so there's no way to write a fixed query)

Hierarchy Level:

```
ID     HierarchyName   FatherLevel
1      "top level"     NULL
2      "medium"        "top level" 
3      "lowest"        "medium"
4      "top level 2"   NULL
5      "lowest 2"      "top level 2"
```

Division:

```
ID    Name            HierachyLevel (I put the names here for ease of understanding but it'd be the IDs)
1     "National"      "top level"
2     "Regional"      "medium"
3     "Northeast"     "lowest"
4     "North"         "lowest"
5     "Southeast"     "lowest"
6     "International" "top level 2"
7     "Europe"        "lowest 2"
7     "Asia"          "lowest 2"
```

ZipCode:

```
ID   Code    Division (Same as before, it'd be the IDs instead of the actual names)
1    101     Southeast
2    102     Southeast
3    103     North
4    104     Northeast
5    105     Europe
6    106     Asia
```

So, what I want here is to see how many times the children of the level just below the top level appears in the ZipCode table appears.

In the example listed, for instance, there's medium appearing 4 times (right below top level, and lowest appearing 2 times (right below top level 2).

My final representation of the query I want to build would be:

```
   HierarchyName   Count
   "lowest 2"      2
   "medium"        4
```

This is a pretty loaded question and to be honest I'm not really sure if I'm explaining it well, sorry.

In simpler terms: I want to count how many times the children of the hiearchies right below the top level appear in the Zipcode table through their Divisions.

Edit: Only the lowest level of the hierarchy will appear on the Zipcode table, and what I want to count is how many times the children of the second level would appear on the Zipcode.

Comment: From your example I gather that you want to count the occurrences of the second from the top + all of its children? Because `Regional` (level = `medium`) does not appear in the zipcode table, but its children (Southeast/North/Northeast) do (4 times). This seems to contradict the "how many times the level **just below** the top level appears" though.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it! In fact, it's only ever the lowest level that will appear on the Zipcode table.

Comment: Gonna add that to the description, thanks a lot @Marth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dCX1w2o28Xfmx5qvVxfhHw/2) has a solution.

First get a count of `zip_code` by `division`

```
with recursive divs as (
  select d.id as division_id, 
         d.name as division_name, 
         d.hierarchy_level_id,
         count(*) filter (where z.code is not null) as zip_count
    from division d
         left join zip_code z
                on z.division_id = d.id
   group by d.id, d.name, d.hierarchy_level_id
),
```

Perform the recursion

```
tree as (
  select h.id, h.hierarchy_name, h.father_id, d.division_name, d.zip_count,
         1 as tier, array[h.hierarchy_name] as hier_path
    from hierarchy_level h
         join divs d 
           on d.hierarchy_level_id = h.id
   where h.father_id is null
  union all
  select c.id, c.hierarchy_name, c.father_id, d.division_name, d.zip_count,
         f.tier + 1, f.hier_path||c.hierarchy_name
    from tree f
         join hierarchy_level c
           on c.father_id = f.id
         join divs d 
           on d.hierarchy_level_id = c.id
)
```

Join each level to all of its descendants using the `@>` "contains" operator to get the rolled-up `sum()` of `zip_code` values beneath each level.

```
select t.id, t.hierarchy_name, t.father_id, t.division_name,
       t.zip_count, t.tier, t.hier_path,
       sum(coalesce(c.zip_count, 0)) + t.zip_count as total_zip_count
  from tree t
       left join tree c
              on c.tier > t.tier
             and c.hier_path @> t.hier_path
 group by t.id, t.hierarchy_name, t.father_id, t.division_name,
          t.zip_count, t.tier, t.hier_path
 order by t.hier_path;
```

I left all the "show your work" information in the fiddle so you can see what is happening.  You can cut it down to what you want by changing the `select` list, adding a `where` clause, and dropping `t.division_name` from both the `select` list and the `group by`.

Comment: The [array[h.hierarchy_name] as hier_path] part of the code isn't working. It asks for a explicit cast type, and then when I cast a type it still doesn't really work, and without it the "contains" part doesn't work either.

Comment: @luifon I ran it just now in the DB Fiddle here:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dCX1w2o28Xfmx5qvVxfhHw/3  If you are doing it differently, then what is the exact error message you get?

Comment: Literally just got it to work, had to cast everything as text[] for it to work, but it did. Now my problem is that the query keeps running forever.

Comment: Can you please put your query into your question?  It sounds like you have a loop in your `hierarchy_level` table.

Comment: no loop, the query worked fine after 42 minutes, though the results were staggeringly wrong, so while there's no loop I've probably made a mistake somewhere. Anyways, I'll keep trying, but unfortunately I can't post the "actual" query here. Thanks a lot for all the help though.

Comment: @luifon  Good luck!  I suggest breaking the problem down to recursively doing only the hierarchy and then adding the other pieces into it.

Answer (score 0):

updated variant, must do the job:

```
WITH recursive levels AS (
  SELECT id, 1 as level, HierarchyName, null::int as l2_parent 
   FROM Hierarchy WHERE FatherLevel IS NULL
  UNION
  SELECT h.id, levels.level+1, h.HierarchyName,
         COALESCE(l.l2_parent, CASE WHEN l.level=2 THEN l.id ELSE NULL END)
   FROM Hierarchy AS h JOIN levels AS l ON l.id = h.FatherLevel
)
SELECT HierarchyName, count(*)
FROM Division As d
JOIN levels AS l
  ON d.HierachyLevel = l.id
 AND l.l2_parent IS NOT NULL
JOIN ZipCode AS z
  ON d.id = z.division
GROUP BY HierarchyName;
```

Comment: This comes really close to what I wanted, but unfortunately it doesn't work (as is).^

Only the lowest Divisions have direct relations to Zip, but what I want to count is the total amount for the children of each level 2 Hierarchy.

Your query is ALMOST there, but something is missing.

Nonetheless, it's been MUCH helpful in trying to find the right conditions, thanks a lot!

Comment: Clarification: What I want is to count the sum of all children for the level 2 of the hierarchy